# Is it possible to run debugging application on second screen by default in IntellIJ

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, multiple-monitors

I would like to run and debug an application on second screen by default, while having IDE displaying on first screen?

**UPDATE**

I don't need to show debug window on second screen, I need to show target application's window on second screen!

Answer (score 0):

1. in the debug view, click on the gear
2. select "Floating Mode" or "Window Mode" in the menu
3. drag the debug view to second screen

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need to show debug window on second screen, I need to show target application's window on second screen!